# Alert message is not displayed using Asp.net ajax

Tags: asp.net, json, ajax, webforms

The alert message is not displayed after add record into the database using Asp.net Ajax.record is add into the database successfully.Alert is not displaying. I attached the code below what I tried so far below.after add record how to return to the ajex success function to display  alert("success");

**Form Design**

```
<form  id="frmProject" runat="server">
            <div>
                <label class="form-label">First Name</label>     
               <input type="text" id="fname" class="form-control"  />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" align="left">
             <label class="form-label">Age</label>
                <input type="text" id="age" class="form-control"  />
            </div>
            <div> 
               <input type="button" id="b1" value="add" class="form-control" onclick="addProject()" />

            </div>
        </form>
```

**Ajex**

```
  function addProject() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'insert.aspx',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    data: {fname: $('#fname').val(), age: $('#age').val()},
                    success: function (data) {         
                        alert("success");
                        get_all();
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        console.log(xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });

                }
```

**insert.aspx**

```
 public static string GetData(string fname, int age)
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=.; Initial Catalog = jds; Integrated Security= true;");
                string sql = "insert into record values('" + fname + "','" + age + "')";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                return HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID;
            }
```

Comment: Is the console outputting any errors?  If you place a console.log statement in the success function, does it log?

Comment: I modify the insert.aspx page it is getting error on  string sql here

Comment: no error displayed in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use web method for Ajax request

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession= true)]
public static string GetData(string fname,int age)    
{    
   // place your logic here
   return HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID;    
}
```

Your Ajax request

```
$('#b1').click(function () {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'insert.aspx/GetData',
        type: "POST",
        data: {fname: $('#fname').val(), age: $('#age').val()},
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: public static string GetData(string fname, int age)
                {
                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=.; Initial Catalog = jds; Integrated Security= true;");
                    string sql = "insert into record values('" + fname + "','" + age + "')";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                    return HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID;
                }    it is not working sir no error displayed

Comment: [WebMethod(EnableSession= true)] is not working i am using Asp.net Simple forms not MVC

Comment: can you write the code for me sir it is easy to understand

Comment: is your sql query is ok. may be if you have more column then specify cilumn also in insert query. insert into record(col1,col2) values(val,val2)